# node.js download file with free public proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, download

I would like to write an application using Node.js. The purpose of application is to download the file specified in URL, by giving the URL parameter. For instance, I would like to download .png file in URL http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/header/intl/CNNi_Logo_new.png. I can write that code. But I don't want the other side to see my IP (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx). I want to use a public proxy while downloading this file. I mean that when I download this file, my IP must appear as 209.170.151.142:7808 for example (one of the IP addresses in http://free-proxy-list.net/), but not my IP.

How I can code this in node.js?

regards...

Comment: .. and are you asking this question via some proxy?

Comment: No i only try to learn how to code in this manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `request` module can take a proxy configuration option: https://github.com/mikeal/request

Something like this (untested):

```
var request = require('request');
request({ 
  url: 'http://domain.com/path/to/image.png',
  proxy: 'http://IP.of.proxy'
}, function (err, res, imgBuffer) {
  // check for presence of err here
  // do something with imgBuffer, like save it to a file
})
```